# RANDBETWEEN excel function giving errors

Tags: excel

I'm pasting in the formula:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014, 1, 1),DATE(2015, 1, 1))
```

which is mentioned in several tutorials but getting the Excel "error with function message". I'm in Ireland which is a different format but either way it doesn't work.

Anything else I have to do to generate random dates?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dRa5ETB.pnge]

Comment: Yeah its strange. Newest Excel?

Comment: It works for me in office 2013

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN` is only available as a native function in Excel 2007 and higher. If you're on Excel 2003 or lower you will need to enable the Analysis Toolpak add-in.  See here for how to do so: https://www.add-ins.com/Analysis_ToolPak.htm

Comment: I just downloaded excel as a student from Microsoft. Very latest version. http://i.imgur.com/dRa5ETB.png

Comment: You could try removing the spaces from the formula (though that usually shouldn't matter).  Alternately, many non US versions of Excel use a semicolon `;` as the formula argument delimiter instead of the comma.  Could try replacing the commas with semicolons to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Like this =RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014;1;1),DATE(2015;1;1)) ? doesnt seem to work. Same error. However strangely enough i think youre onto something because the predictive text shows a semicolon rather than a comma.

Comment: You'll notice there's a comma in there still.  Need to replace all commas with semicolons: `=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014;1;1);DATE(2015;1;1))`

Comment: Beautiful. I think about 3 people replied with the same answer at the same time. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
=RANDBETWEEN(41640,42005)
```

And format as date.

For some countries:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(41640;42005)
```

And format as date.

And if the 2nd works maybe just:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014; 1; 1);DATE(2015; 1; 1))
```

Comment: same error with that. However it worked earlier as i used the RANDBETWEEN function with numbers earlier but not dates. http://imgur.com/QCPkn5X. This is very strange.

Comment: When entering =RANDBETWEEN(41640;42005)?

Comment: That works. Its a semicolon its after. Now how do i use the semicolon in the date? Between the StartDate an EndDate or between the day/month/year?

Comment: Between them.. Just replace the , with ;

Comment: Great stuff. Edit your OP as ive marked it the correct answer.

Comment: Made all 3 options so others might use it!